# How can the sum of squares be negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics, maxima-minima

> If $a,b,c,d$ are the roots of the equation $x^4-Kx^3+Kx^2+Lx+M=0$, where $K,L,M$ are real numbers, then the mininmum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ is?

My answer:

$\sum a=K,\ \sum ab=K\implies$

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=K^2-2K=(K-1)^2-1$. For $K=1$, $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)_{min}=-1$

This matches with the answer in fact, but how can sum of squares ever result in **NEGATIVE**.

What's the intuition behind this answer is it wrong or I'm going the wrong way.

Comment: Hint: The coefficients are real, but what about the roots?

Comment: Are you aware about complex numbers?

Comment: Complex roots...

Comment: @TobErnack yes a bit of.

Comment: The sum of the squares of the roots of $x^2+1=0$ is also negative.

Comment: Question: what does "the sum of a equals K" (similarly for ab) have to do with this? I understand why the answer can be negative but not how this substitution helps.

Comment: @SubSevn theory of equations. (hint)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $K=1,$ that is, $$f(x)=x^4-x^3+x^2+Lx+M.$$ We have that

$$f''(x)=2(6x^2-3x+1).$$ Note that $$f''=0$$ has no real roots. Thus $f'=0$ has a real root and so $f=0$ has at most two real roots. In other word, at least two roots of the equation $$f(x)=0$$ are complex. Thus there is no contradiction with the fact that the sum of the squares of the roots is $-1.$

If $L=M=0$ then the roots are $0$ (double) and $\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt {-3}}{2}=\dfrac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}.$ We have that

$$0^2+0^2+\left(\dfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2=-1.$$

Comment: $f''=0$ has no real roots, I'm not aware of this can you explain why?

Comment: Because $6x^2+3x+1=0\iff x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{\color{red}{9-24}}}{12}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

the roots of the quartic can be complex numbers and in this case we have couples of conjugate roots of the form $\alpha \pm i \beta$ and:
$$
(\alpha+i\beta)^2 +(\alpha-i\beta)^2=2\alpha^2-2\beta^2
$$